# Magento 2 Upgrade manually

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I want to upgrade our Magento 2.1.0 instance to 2.1.4. Unfortunately I can't use the System Upgrade from the backend and I can't use composer. Both aren't working because of old TLS versions or old CURL versions. Because of various reasons I can't do anything about this. Is it possible to upgrade Magento 2 manually by simply downloading the archive and overwriting the files?

Comment: It should be possible to update that way but you'd still need to run some magento CLI commands.

Comment: You mean like "setup:static-content:deploy" etc.? That's no problem.

Comment: Yeah, you need to run `setup:upgrade` to upgrade the database and also run compilation and static content deployment.

Comment: I tried it out and everything worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The corner stone of this approach will be the composer dependencies.
Updated magento core modules might require new modules or newer versions of old ones. You gonna need composer up and running to resolve all those issues.